# Sign android application

Tags: android, sign, decompiling, recompile, apktool

I decompiled an android app with apktool.
I translated it to my language.
After it, I recompiled the application.
When I sign app with SignApp.rar (you can search and download it) I can install app but when I open app, it exit immediately (without force close error).
I didn't change package name and author information. I just translated it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To sign an android apk you have to use your own key, or testsign.jar (I've never heard about SignApp.rar).

You can use testsign.jar with this command:

`java -jar testsign.jar unsigned.apk signed.apk`

If it still crash, then you have broken something.